# Post FormViewModel entire SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem on my post Create controller action.
I'm using a FormViewModel as the action parameter but it contains a SelectList property that is posted without value (null).
I'd like to know if its possible to bind the entire SelectList and receive it's value in my action parameter.
Other properties in FormViewModel like int, string, etc, are populated correctly.

```
public class ClienteFormViewModel
{
    public SelectList Routes { get; set; }
    ...

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ClientFormViewModel clientForm)
{
    clientForm.Routes //I'd like to have the SelectList but is null
    ...

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Client.route, Model.Routes, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I've also tried to do a custom model binder (I don't know if it's the correct way) so I've created a hidden property for the Routes property and I've tried to read it in the model binder but I't only gets System.Web.Mvc.SelectList not the desired object.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Routes)

request.Form.Get("Routes")  //"System.Web.Mvc.SelectList"   string
```

Note that my controller Create Action in the model binder solution is the following:

```
    public ActionResult Create([ModelBinder(typeof(ModelBinders.ClientCustomDataBinder))] ClientFormViewModel clientForm)
```

Comment: Your not (and should not) generate a form control for each input of each property of each `SelectListItem` so its not sent in the post request. What make you think you should want it? Just populate it again if you need to return the view because `ModelState` is invalid.

Comment: My temporary solution is your suggestion (var routes = routesRepo.GetRoutes(); and assign it to the formviewmodel) but I'm convinced that could be a way to achieve that without doing that call again.

Comment: Read the first comment again. You would need to create a hidden input for **each** property of **each** `SelectListItem` in the collection!. But that would be crazy and degrade performance. And why in the world do you think you need this

Comment: Yes, I understand your first comment. I've readed that post before http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ and I think that could be another way. Maybe not and should retrieve data again as final solution but I have another FormViewModel with more SelectList and I think that could be faster

Comment: Hi if you want get the value of the dropdownlist  selected value , then check the name of the dropdownlist . I hope in your scenario , it will   ClienteFormViewModel.Client.route property, check that property you should have the value .